# Where can I mix-in XML from another namespace?

Tags: xml, svg, xhtml, xml-namespaces

SVG can be included in XHTML. As can MathML. But which rules govern *where* any XML dialect can be included in another? And does the included element has to be the usual root element?

I want to include HTML tables in SVG, as an example. I don't care much about a working example (I have one), I care about the rules and correctness.

Comment: As long as you use XHTML (read XML) you can put that into SVG pretty much anywhere you like. That's completely unrestricted. And as long as all namespaces are declared properly (otherwise the SVG would not load anyway) you are not required to start at `<html>`. Practical restrictions apply, i.e. you should not throw a `<td>` at the browser's rendering engine without setting up a `<table>` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XHTML is just the XML Syntax of HTML. So it follows the content model rules of HTML. That says that the SVG `<svg>` element and the MathML `<math>` element are [Flow Content](http://w3c.github.io/html/dom.html#flow-content). That is, they can only go where `Flow Content` is expected. So for example, they can't be the children of a `ul`, `ol`, `table`, `tr` etc. element. And no other SVG or MathML elements are defined as valid children of any element in the HTML namespace.

So you can't *validly* include elements from other namespaces in XHTML. If you do include such elements, then it's no longer pure XHTML, but XHTML + something-else.

Comment: So it is a mistake to assume that any XML-application can be included in any other XML-application if the latter does not explicitly allow that? -- And your example of "XHTML + something-else" being a new standard, not a per-se valid extension.